# Field table renamed with field_deleted_data_<id> and field_config , field_config_instance table set deleted status 1

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-field-api

Suddenly I am facing some issue at Drupal 7 site.

Here in my project I user Profile2 module .

We have multiple profile type. Each profile type has some field.

Suddenly field_data and field_revision table rename with `field_deleted_data_<id>` and `field_deleted_revision_<id>`.

`field_config` and `field_config_instance` set field deleted status to 1.

I can't understand what wrong going on. Any one have any idea regarding this issue.

Please help me.

Comment: i am also facing same issue.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue

Comment: Did you use Feature module ? Sometimes if features not saved with new field , on revert features can place field to field deletion queue with flag to 1 into field_config tables